# Cassandra IN clause for non primary key column

Tags: cassandra, cql

I want to use the IN clause for the non-primary key column in Cassandra. Is it possible? if it is not is there any alternate or suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Three possible solutions**

- Create a secondary index. This is not recommended due to performance problems.
- See if you can designate that column in the existing table as part of the primary key
- Create another denormalised table that table is optimised for your query. i.e data model by query pattern

**Update:**

And also even after you move that to primary key, operations with IN clause can be further optimised. I found this [cassandra lookup by list of primary keys in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62643342/cassandra-lookup-by-list-of-primary-keys-in-java) very useful