# cassandra lookup by list of primary keys in java

Tags: java, cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I am implementing a feature which requires looking up Cassandra by a list of primary keys.

Below is an example data where id is primary key

```
mytable
id          column1
1           423
2           542
3           678
4           45534
5           435634
6           2435
7           678
8           4564
9           546
```

Most of my queries a lookup by id, but for some special cases I would like to get data for a list of ids.
The way I am currently doing is a follows:

```
public Object fetchFromCassandraForId(int id);

int ids[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
List<Object> results;
for(int id: ids) {
  results.add(fetchFromCassandraForId(id));
}
```

This results in issuing multiple network call to cassandra, Is it possible to batch this somehow, therefore i would like to know if cassandra supports fast lookup by list of ids

```
select coulmn1 from mytable where id in (1, 3, 5, 7, 9);
```

?
Any help or pointers would be appreciated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `id` is the full primary key, then Cassandra supports this, although it's not recommended from performance point of view:

- request is sent to coordinator node
- coordinator node finds a replica for each of the `id`, and send individual request to them
- wait for results from every node, collect them to result set & send back

As result:

- all your sub-queries need to wait for slowest of the replicas
- you have an additional network hope from coordinator to replica
- you put more pressure to the coordinator node as it need to keep results in memory

If you do a lot of parallel, asynchronous requests for each of the `id` values from application, then you:

- avoid an additional hop - if you're using prepared statements with token-aware load balancing, then query is sent directly to replicas
- you may start to process results as you get them, not waiting for everything

So sending parallel asynchronous requests could be faster than sending one request with `IN`...