# cql query in operator with composite key with zipped list

Tags: python, cassandra, cql

I am trying to pass a zipped list some how to a cql query for cassandra.

Say my composite key is (value1, value2)

Here is something I would like to do ( I know it doesn't work but hopefully this explains it)

```
zippedlist = zip(value1list, value2list)

Select * from table where value1 and value2 in zippedlist
```

Currently I would have each key have an in operator with a list (which would work but I need the select query to be the set in my zipped list (specific combinations need to be selected). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such thing in the CQL.  But in general, the `IN` query on the partition key is the bad idea - it adds more pressure to coordinating node, etc. (see [this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62643342/cassandra-lookup-by-list-of-primary-keys-in-java/62643869#62643869)).

I would recommend just to send `len(zippedlist)` async queries, and collect data on the client.  The [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.24/getting_started/#asynchronous-queries), even has an example for that, that you can use as-is...